# Pass a delegate in parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I have

```
Function Bar(s As String) ...
```

I need to create a function

```
Me.Foo(myInt, AddressOf Bar)
```

How should I write the Foo's signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of the generic Func(Of Type) keyword is probably the easiest.

```
Public Function Foo(i As Integer, f As Func(Of String, Integer)) As String
    Dim i2 = f.Invoke("test")
    Return "42"
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

[This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117623/delegates-as-parameters-in-vb-net)

Declare your delegate signature:

```
Public Delegate Sub Format(ByVal value As String)
```

Define your Test function:

```
Public Sub CheckDifference(ByVal A As Integer, _
                           ByVal B As Integer, _
                           ByVal format As Format)
    If (B - A) > 5 Then
        format.Invoke(String.Format( _
        "Difference ({0}) is outside of acceptable range.", (B - A)))
    End If
End Sub
```

Somewhere in your code call your Test function:

```
CheckDifference(Foo, Bar, AddressOf log.WriteWarn)
```

Or

```
CheckDifference(Foo, Bar, AddressOf log.WriteError)
```

Comment: should I really declare a Public Delegate for each king of function call like this, even if I don't use them?